# What native speakers call an on-air sign?

Tags: word-choice

[image]

The sign that expresses broadcasting is on progress.

Comment: What do you call it.  Does it have a special name other than "on air sign/light"

Comment: We just call it 온에어 ('on-air'). 온에어에 불이 들어오다 ('on-air' is lighting up').

Comment: I see you use a phonetic rather than a literal translation.  That is just "on air" spelled in hangul.

Comment: Yes! you got it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no special name for it - it is often called an "on-air *light*" (as it lights up) in radio stations. In recording studios, the equivalent is just referred to as "*the red light*" or "*the recording light*".

Recording artists who suffer from nerves in the studio are said to have "red light fever".

Comment: For what it's worth, searching for "on-air light broadcasting" brings up lots of trade supply results that use that name. I'm not sure if there's another specific term for it (and some places do just use a plain light, not a sign) but "on-air sign" would be how most ordinary people would describe it, I think!

Comment: @cactustictacs If you're looking to purchase one, it may be called a 'sign', but once in use it is definitely a 'light'. As a sign, it will always read 'on air' - what matters in use is whether the light is on or off.

Comment: Oh I just mean it's not always actually a sign that says *ON AIR*, sometimes it's just a light bulb above a door, but either way it's an "on-air" light, like you say, and "on-air *thing*" is how it's described on trade sites. I wasn't disagreeing, just backing up your answer